# Preserve SharePoint display formatting on my custom SPGridView

Tags: sharepoint, moss, wss

I'v used SharePoint:SPGridView control in aspx page to display data as I would like it (It's as simple as two column grid with no filtering/grouping or whatsoever).

But how do I inherit formatting, so my SPGridView would look something like **default sharepoint list**?

It now appears as:

[alt text http://img193.imageshack.us/img193/9829/ss20090612115512.png](http://img193.imageshack.us/img193/9829/ss20090612115512.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I`v found the solution.

I had to add reference to core.css file on the aspx page:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/_layouts/1033/styles/core.css" />
```